# Replacing a value in an anonymous type used in an actionlink with javascript

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to pass through the selected value from a Drop down list to an actionlink.

It goes something like this at the moment but doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#SiteDropDown').change(function () {
        var value = $('#SiteDropDown option:selected').text();
        $('#editlink').attr('href', value);
    });
});
</script>


@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name) </td>
        <td> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SiteReference) </td>
        <td> @Html.DropDownList("SiteDropDown") </td>
        <td> @Html.ActionLink("View", "ViewInvoice", new { siteId = item.Id, filename =     "editlink" }) </td>
```

What I want is for the Javascript to replace the string "editlink" in the Actionlink but cant seem to get it right. I know the Javascript gets the selected value from the dropdownlist ok. But I cant find the right way to add it to my Actionlink. The dropdownlist contains a list of files, If I hardcode the filename = with a valid filename the controller handles the request ok.

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated.

thanks in advance,

Mat

What I did in the end was this (i'm sure it could be a lot neater etc but it works):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#editlink').on('mouseenter', function () { 
            var value = $('#SiteDropDown option:selected').text();
            var value1 = "\\" + value;
            var link = document.getElementById('editlink').outerHTML;
            var newlink = link.replace(/xx/, value1);
            document.getElementById('editlink').outerHTML = newlink;
            document.getElementById('Button1').value = newlink;

        });
    });
</script>

@Html.ActionLink("View", "ViewInvoice", new { siteId = item.Id, filename = "xx" }, new { id = "editlink" })
```

Thanks for your answer NaNpx, it got me thinking about what I was actually doing i.e. amending the HTML rather than amending the c# code in the razor syntax.

Comment: Could you post the output HTML code the Razor engine produces?

Comment: I don't seem to be able to post the whole output as I'm limited by the number of characters allowed, this is a section: <select id="SiteDropDown" name="SiteDropDown"><option value="Mats Site 1">A-Z COLOR - 9ADH000001-JUIL.2012.pdf</option> <option value="Mats Site 2">A-Z COLOR-F1304003404-H-AOUT-2013.pdf</option>
 <option value="Mats Site 2">A-Z COLOR-F1304003892-H-SEPT-2013.pdf</option>
 </select></td>

            <td><a href="/Home/ViewInvoice?siteId=3&amp;filename=editlink">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like you want to only replace the 'editlink' part of you href string, but you are replacing the entire href with the text from your selected option.  Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/Uz784/

First it takes the original version of the editlink href and stores it as data in with the select element.  This way as the string gets updated on change, there is a common way of searching and replacing.  The rest is pretty much the same.

```
var siteDropDown = $('#SiteDropDown'),
    editLink = $('#editLink');

siteDropDown.data('editLink',editLink.attr('href')).on({
    'change': function(){
        var href = siteDropDown.data('editLink').replace('filename=editlink','filename=' + encodeURIComponent(siteDropDown.find('option:selected').text()));
        editLink.attr('href',href);
    }
}).trigger('change');
```